# websocket problem: cannot connect to node.js server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, node.js, websocket

I've got a node.js server up and running with express and i'm trying to establish a websocket connection using socket.io server-side and chrome 12 client-side. When I try to connect, socket.io outputs a debug message saying "destroying non-socket.io upgrade" and the code in my connection handler doesn't run. Also on the client-side the readyState of my socket is 2 (CLOSING).

[edit]
readyState of the socket changed from 0 to 2

Comment: are you using the socket.io.js on the client to connect to the server?

Comment: Can you put your code snippet here (or a link to github)?

Comment: What version of Node.js and socket.io are you using?

Comment: Is there a server side implementation of WebSocket that doesn't require a client library (that is, with which I can use the built-in browser WebSocket methods)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're inserting the socket.io.js file into your client code and using it. If you try to create your own websocket on the client-side, you'll probably run into problems.

Do something like this for your server:

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

and something like this for the HTML file you're serving:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Make sure you're serving `/socket.io/socket.io.js` from your webserver dir. Then all you have to do is watch your console log in the web browser's Developer environment from the Options or with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) when you go to the page.

Comment: When I try to add socket.io.js into my client, I get an error that the client can't find "require". I looked at the socket.io.js code and it uses require, which I thought was a server side (ie, node) thing only, not a JavaScript in the browser supported thing. Is there another library that we need to include in the client that implements a client-side "require"? or am I missing something?

Comment: @Elisabeth you should make that into a new question. You won't be using require() in the client. In the client, you'll use <script src=...>

Comment: I figured it out; it was that you must serve the client code using the socket.io server so it can do some magic on the client code.